# Consultation regarding dates in jQuery-mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i need to add 10 days to my date picker.

my code for date picker

```
<label for="bday" style="text-align:right">Pick Date</label>
<input type="date" name="bday" id="bday">
```

How to insert to variable what I chose and then add 10 days to the date ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should create new Date object and assign it as a value to the input.
Use this construtor:

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

This code using jQuery works for your case:

```
//Here we create a method that will format the date the way input type date wants it: 
Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
   var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
   var mm = (this.getMonth()+1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
   var dd  = this.getDate().toString();
   return yyyy + '-' + (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]) + '-' + (dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]); // padding
  };

$(document).ready(function(){
    var bDay = new Date(1990, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);

    $('#bday').attr('value',bDay.yyyymmdd());
    var currentDate = new Date($('#bday').attr('value'));
    //Here we add 10 days
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 10);
    $('#bday').attr('value',currentDate.yyyymmdd());

});
```

Comment: i try this, and i got in date NaN NaN NaN ??  Maybe I'm doing it wrong use ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this (I have used jQuery for this sample):

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    $('#bday').change(function(){
        var newVal = new Date(Date.parse($(this).val()));
        newVal.setDate(newVal.getDate() + 10);
        $('#result').html(newVal);
    });
});
</script>
```

See demo: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9t58pw07/)
I know you're using this for mobile browser but you may test it using Google Chrome.

Comment: thank for the help ! it works on chrome but on safari - Does not work. how it can work on safari too ?

Comment: This is right, safari seems just don't support the input with type date yet. I guess if you need full cross browser compatibility you should implement it use jQuery UI (or if you will be using it for mobile then jQuery Mobile, see date picker at http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/datepicker/).